# Excluding a pattern without chaining greps

Tags: grep

```
# spam.txt
src/blahblah/potato.py
src/migrations/helloworld.py
spam/blahblah/thing.py
src/thingy/other.cpp
```

I have this:

```
$ cat spam.txt | grep 'src.*\.py' | grep --invert-match '/migrations/'
src/blahblah/potato.py
```

How can I chain the exclude into the same pattern?  i.e. how can I write the `'pattern???'` below so that I get the same result?

```
$ grep 'pattern???' spam.txt
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible... I've never seen a way to do it in a single statement.  Sed, awk, or Perl have some compound statements that might feel like a single statement, but really it's just another way of tacking together two separate filters.  I can suggest -v though instead of --invert-match as less typing.

Comment: As an example using a compound sed statement:   sed -n '/migrations/!s/src.*py/&/p' spam.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better

```sh
awk '/src/ && /\.py/ && ! /migrations/' spam.txt
```

[Example](http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/blob/13a9f58/apt-cyg#L296-L304)